# Reinicialización de un DataTable

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatables

Estoy trabajando con un `Datatable()` el cual me esta dando problemas a la hora de reinicializarlo, ya probé distintos métodos y no me han dado resultado.

La cuestión es que el sitio al cargarlo por primera vez me carga el `DataTable()` sin ningún problema.

`DataTable` Principal:

```
var dt = $('#traslados').DataTable({
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
            'ajax': "<? echo base_url('Inicio/obtenerTraslados'); ?>",
            bAutoWidth: false,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "searching": false,
            "columns": [
                {"data": "ides"},
                {"data": "Status"},
                {"data": "Folio"},
                {"data": "Fecha"},
                {"data": "Nombre"},
            ]
        });
```

Estoy haciendo una especie de filtro por medio de un `select` y un `boton`:

```
<div class="form-group input-group m-b-2 m-t-0" id="selectstatus2">
    <select id="filtro_estatus" class="form-control">
        <option value="8">En Traslado</option>
        <option value="20">Recibidos</option>
        <option value="14">En Fila ML</option>
        <option value="15">En Fila GDL</option>
        <option value="17">En Fila CAC</option>
        <option value="16">Enviado CAC</option>
        <option value="9">Enviado GDL</option>
        <option value="10">En Suc. Talavera</option>
        <option value="12">En Suc. Telcel</option>
        <option value="13">En Suc. Unefon</option>
        <option value="11">En Suc. México</option>
    </select> <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="creafiltro" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Filtrar</button>
</span>
</div>
```

Y al momento que se realiza un `clic` entonce se procede a destruir el `DataTable` y a inicializar el nuevo:

```
$('#creafiltro').click(function () {
            dt.clear().destroy();
            dt = $('#traslados').DataTable({
                "order": [[0, "desc"]],
                'ajax': "<?= base_url('Inicio/obtenerTrasladosf?folio=')?>" + $('#filtro_estatus').val(),
                bAutoWidth: false,
                serverSide: true,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "searching": false,
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "ides"},
                    {"data": "Status"},
                    {"data": "Folio"},
                    {"data": "Fecha"},
                    {"data": "Nombre"},
                ],
            });
        });
```

Si me elimina el `DataTable()` existente pero me inicializa el nuevo sin cargar los datos y no se porque.

Estuve haciendo pruebas por medio de `getJSON` para ver que mis datos se estuvieran retornando de manera correcta y si sin problema se retornan.

```
$.getJSON('<?php echo base_url('Inicio/obtenerTrasladosf?folio=')?>' + $('#filtro_estatus').val(),
                function (data) {
                    console.log($data);
                });
```

Ejemplo: Selecciono el `value` 8 del `select` y le presiono a `Filtrar` y el `getJSON` me retorna lo siguiente:

```
Dump => array(1) {
  ["data"] => array(3) {
    [0] => array(7) {
      ["ides"] => string(2) "85"
      ["Folio"] => string(4) "1234"
      ["Fecha"] => string(19) "19-03-2019 10:18 AM"
      ["id"] => string(1) "8"
      ["Status"] => string(11) "En Traslado"
      ["Nombre"] => string(7) "Eduardo"
      ["Sucursal"] => string(14) "Mario Talavera"
    }
    [3] => array(7) {
      ["ides"] => string(2) "11"
      ["Folio"] => string(4) "1411"
      ["Fecha"] => string(19) "14-03-2019 06:10 PM"
      ["id"] => string(1) "8"
      ["Status"] => string(11) "En Traslado"
      ["Nombre"] => string(5) "Allan"
      ["Sucursal"] => string(14) "Mario Talavera"
    }
    [4] => array(7) {
      ["ides"] => string(2) "42"
      ["Folio"] => string(4) "1412"
      ["Fecha"] => string(19) "15-03-2019 06:32 PM"
      ["id"] => string(1) "8"
      ["Status"] => string(11) "En Traslado"
      ["Nombre"] => string(9) "Asistente"
      ["Sucursal"] => string(14) "Mario Talavera"
    }
  }
}
```

Esto porque el `array` que retorno es `$data['data']`:

```
$data['data'] = $this->Inicio_model->obtenerTrasladosf($id_sucursal, $_REQUEST['folio']);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Pero esa misma `url` que tiene el `getJSON` se la aplico al `ajax` del `DataTable` y no me funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe mencionar que ya eh probado con esto:

```
if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#traslados')) {
    dt.clear().destroy();
}
```

y con esto:

```
$('#teamTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
$('#teamTable').dataTable();
```

Y algunas otras mas que no eh logrado que funcionen. La cuestión es en la inicialización del `DataTable` porque los datos los esta retornando bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realizando una investigación mas en profundidad al fin di con la solución y esta en agregar `bDestroy: true` al `DataTable()`, destruirlo con `$("#traslados").dataTable().fnDestroy();` y inicializarlo con `DataTable()` y no con `dataTable()`:

```
$('#traslados').DataTable({
    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
    'ajax': "<? echo base_url('Inicio/obtenerTraslados'); ?>",
    bDestroy: true,
    bAutoWidth: false,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "searching": false,
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [0],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        }
    ],
    "columns": [
        {"data": "ides"},
        {"data": "Status"},
        {"data": "Folio"},
        {"data": "Fecha"},
        {"data": "Nombre"},
    ]
});
```

y la acción al hacer `clic` quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#creafiltro').click(function () {
    $("#traslados").dataTable().fnDestroy();
    $('#traslados').DataTable({
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        'ajax': "<?= base_url('Inicio/obtenerTrasladosf?folio=')?>" + $('#filtro_estatus').val(),
        bDestroy: true,
        bAutoWidth: false,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "searching": false,
        "paging": false,
        "info": false,
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }
        ],
        "columns": [
            {"data": "ides"},
            {"data": "Status"},
            {"data": "Folio"},
            {"data": "Fecha"},
            {"data": "Nombre"},
        ],
    });
});
```

Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452270/how-to-reinitialize-datatable-in-ajax